# Validacion de fecha y edad con jquery validation asp core mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core, jquery-validate, dataannotations

En mis primeros pasos en asp core mvc estoy tratando de realizar una validación del campo fecha de nacimiento con jquery validation ya que el data annotations no me lo permite o desconozco como realizarlo, la validación consta en primera parte de que el usuario seleccione una fecha distinta a la del día de hoy y al menos seleccione una fecha de hace 5 años para posterior a eso validar la edad en base a la fecha realizando un calculo, como se ve en la imagen es lo que desearía realizar ,la pregunta es como poder realizarlo en base al código que mantengo orita.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#formPaciente').validate({
        rules: {
            txtFecNac: "required",
            txtEdad: {
                required: true,
                Range:[5,90]
            }
        },
        messages: {
            txtFecNac: "La Fecha Nacimiento es requerida",
            txtEdad: {
                required: "Su edad es requerida",
                Range: "La edad debe ser entre 5 y 90"
            }
        },
    });
});
```

Pero mis dudas son como primero como poder calcular la edad en base a la fecha de nacimiento haciendo uso de jquery validation y segundo validar que la fecha de nacimiento al menos en base al calculo de la edad tengo 5 años con lo cual llenaría un campo adicional llamado representante y si es mayor pues continuo normalmente con el sgte campo, cual seria la manera correcta de realizar esta validación.

De antemano agradezco su ayuda y guía.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de varios días buscando la solución, gracias a la comunidad que me brindo su ayuda, dejo aquí la respuesta para las demás personas que necesiten realizar lo mismo o algo parecido, aquí pongo el script como quedaría finalmente.

```
@section scripts{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#FecNacVal").on("change", function () {
                var now = new Date();
                var birthdate = new Date($("#FecNacVal").val()); // Se Procede a calcular en base a la fecha
                var nowyear = now.getFullYear();
                var birthyear = birthdate.getFullYear();
                var age = nowyear - birthyear + 1;
                $('#EdadVal').val(age);
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#FecNacVal").on("change", function () {
                // Accedemos al botón
                var RepresentanteValidacion = document.getElementById('RepPacVal');
                var EdadValidacion = $("#EdadVal").val(); // Obtenemos el Valor del campo Edad
                //console.log(EdadValidacion);
                if (EdadValidacion > 18) { // Validamos si es mayor o menor
                    // evento para el input habilitarlo
                    // console.log("Mayor de edad");
                    RepresentanteValidacion.disabled = RepresentanteValidacion.disabled; // Deshabilitado
                }
                else if (EdadValidacion < 18) {
                    //console.log("Menor de edad");
                    // evento para el input habilitarlo
                    RepresentanteValidacion.disabled = !RepresentanteValidacion.disabled; // Habilitado
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial">

}
```